# In Expo v35 managed workflow, how to handle `Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core`?

Tags: react-native, expo

I use expo SDK v35, and works on the managed workflow (one without eject).

In my project, I face warning whenever I use [`AsyncStorage` as demonstrated by their doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/).

This, however, results in following warning being emitted:

> Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage

I tried to follow the instruction given by this warning, and tried to use `@react-native-community/async-storage`, but it did not succeed; it appears the library requires some linking, which is not available if you want to work inside the Expo's managed workflow.

#### Question

What is the proper way to handle `AsyncStorage` warning when working on expo's managed workflow?

#### Env

- Expo 35.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Recently I began developing a simple app using react native and the expo cli. However, on the react native docs, it seems that asyncStorage is getting deprecated. The solution would normally be to use the react community version but that is not compatible with expo.

https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no scope of linking libraries while using the managed workflow of expo. I've faced similiar issues , and was bound to migrate from expo to pure react native. And expo isnt meant for production as apps are slower. Better i would suggest you to migrate to pure React native . Async storage cant be used otherwise and if deprecated , you will be in a great problem in the future for your app.